# Second radio button always showing selected in PHP

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I have radio buttons on my page and below code, I am using it. If I insert the data into the database then it's sending the correct value.

Now, My issue is, I am on the edit page and every time, The female radio button is showing selected. I don't know why. I am getting the value `1` from the database.

Also, I notice that if I remove the `isset()` then it's working but I don't want to remove it. If I remove the `isset()` then I am getting the error on the edit page

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

```
<?php $info['profile']['gender']=1;?>
  <div class="form-check  ps-0">
        <input type="radio" id="male" class="radio-custom" name="gender" value="1" <?php if(isset($info['profile']['gender'])==1){?> checked="checked" <?php }?>>
        <label for="male" class="radio-custom-label">Male</label>
     </div>
     <div class="form-check">
        <input type="radio" id="female" class="radio-custom" name="gender" value="2" <?php if(isset($info['profile']['gender'])==2){?> checked="checked" <?php }?>>
        <label for="female" class="radio-custom-label">Female</label>
     </div>
```

Comment: You can not check if the result of `isset` is 1 because `isset` only returns true, not the value. You need to have 2 `if`. First check if the variable `isset` then check if the variable is `=== 1`. to note the triple `=` to also check the type of the variable, which you should decide if it's an `int` or a `string` to avoid confusion. E.g.  `if(isset($info['profile']['gender']) && $info['profile']['gender'] ===1) {`

Comment: @AndreaOlivato, I got your point. Test and it's working. Thank you for the help.